# Send a file to a API in Java

Tags: java, api, file, request

I'm using the library QRCodeWriter that create a QR and send it to an API.

The issue is that I have variable *os* where the image is stored, but I can not able to add it to MultipartEntity to send it (commented line).

The error is: *incompatible types: ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to ContentBody entity.addPart("file", os)*

I tried a lot of code to convert the image without success.

Any help will be apreciated

```
    String url =  "https://apiURL.com";
    String accessToken = "123456789";

    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode("https://www.google.com/", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 350, 350);
    BufferedImage image = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
    ImageIO.write(image,"png",os);
    
    context.log(os.toString());
    basicIO.write("TestData");

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    //entity.addPart("file", os);

    HttpResponse returnResponse = Request.Post(url).addHeader("Authorization", accessToken).body(entity).execute().returnResponse();
    context.log("Response status: " + returnResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    context.log(EntityUtils.toString(returnResponse.getEntity()));
```

Comment: maybe `entity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(os));` will help

Comment: error: incompatible types: ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be converted to File entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(os));

Comment: Maybe this will help you, [examples](https://www.javatips.net/api/org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.bytearraybody)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works changing:

```
entity.addPart("file", os);
```

to:

```
entity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(os.toByteArray(), "qr.png"));
```